# enviar somente dados preenchidos PHP ARRAY

Tags: php, html, mysql

Boa noite pessoal! tabela já está quase pronta só que preciso pega o valor que for selecionado no campo quantidade for menor que 0 não enviar para o banco de dados so enviar o valor que eu colocar no campo $quantidade que for relevante maior que 0 meu ajudem por favor...

campos da tabelas html.

```
<tr>
            <td><input type="text" readonly class="form-control" name="codigo[]" id="inlineFormInputGroup" value="091822"></td>
            <td><input type="text" readonly class="form-control" name="material[]" id="inlineFormInputGroup" value="TOMATE GRAPE 180"></td>
            <td><input type="number" class="form-control" name="quantidade[]" id="inlineFormInputGroup" placeholder="Valor" ></td>
     
</tr>
<tr>
            <td><input type="text" readonly class="form-control" name="codigo[]" id="inlineFormInputGroup" value="091822"></td>
            <td><input type="text" readonly class="form-control" name="material[]" id="inlineFormInputGroup" value="TOMATE GRAPE 180"></td>
            <td><input type="number" class="form-control" name="quantidade[]" id="inlineFormInputGroup" placeholder="Valor" ></td>
     
</tr>
```

CODIGO EM PHP

```
<body>
<?php 

$material = $_POST["material"];
$codigo = $_POST["codigo"];
$quantidade= $_POST["quantidade"];  PRECISO QUE  ENVIE ESSE VALOR SE ELE FOR PREENCHIDO MAIOR QUE 0.
$total_codigo = count($codigo);

$conn = mysqli_connect($servidor,$dbusuario,$dbsenha,$dbname);
mysqli_select_db($conn,'$dbname');

for($i = 0; $i  <  $total_codigo;  $i++){
   $sql = "INSERT INTO tblavitaperdas (material,codigo,quantidade) VALUES 
           ('$material[$i]','$codigo[$i]','$quantidade[$i]')";
 
 if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
    echo "<script>alert('Salvei seus dados !'); window.location = 'perdaslavita.php';</script>";
    
    
    }else{
     echo "Deu errro: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
    }
  
    
    }



mysqli_close($conn);
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: não pode fazer  uma validação antes de fazer o insert (`if ($quantidade > 0)`?

Comment: pior que não estou conseguindo fazer essa validação ja tentei varias formas.

Answer (score 1):

Poderia fazer assim por exemplo:

```
$materialarray = $_POST["material"];
$codigoarray = $_POST["codigo"];
$quantidadearray= $_POST["quantidade"];

for ($i = 0; $i < count($codigoarray); $i++) {
   $material   = $materialarray[$i];
   $codigo     = $codigoarray[$i];
   $quantidade = $quantidadearray[$i];

   if ($quantidade > 0) {
       $sql = "INSERT INTO tblavitaperdas (material,codigo,quantidade) VALUES 
           ('$material','$codigo','$quantidade')";
   }
}
```